# Modifying @content inside a SASS mixin

Tags: css, sass, mixins

I have a series of modules that are all available in different colours, each with their own complimentary colours.  I have a map containing all these colours:

```
$colors : (
    blue : (
        main : #0079c1,
        dark : #00456f
    ),
    red : (
        main : #e52643,
        dark : #a01f31
    ),
    ...
)
```

What I want to do is pass styles to a mixin, which then repeats those styles for each colour - in order to do this I need to be able to modify the @content, and I can't see a way of doing this.

My [current best solution](http://codepen.io/gingerchris/pen/zqdVjK) works, but requires me to repeat the @each block every time I want to use it.  I'd rather this part

```
@each $color, $variants in $colors {
    $main: map-get($variants, main);
    $dark: map-get($variants, dark);
    ...
}
```

Be inside my mixin, ([like this, not working](http://codepen.io/gingerchris/pen/PNKrXX)) but if I do that then my $main and $dark variables are not defined and an error is thrown.

Is something like this possible?  Is there a way of expanding variables in content inside a mixin rather than before?